# Django Pagination always returns "That page number is less than 1"

Tags: python, django, pagination, django-views

I am new to Django and trying to get the Pagination system to work.  Whatever I do I get the error when the page attempts to render.  It is the return render line that is raising the error in the view.py code.

Exception Type: EmptyPage

Exception Value : That page number is less than 1

I have checked the pagination object that is being passed to the renderer.  It says "< Page 1 of 26>".  scoresPaginator.object_list shows the correct data objects.  Print statements in the code all return the expected values.

I have removed all code from the template so there should be no problem there.  All is does now is print a title.  I have updated the pagination module to the latest version.

The reason for the POST data collection is when the Pagination is working I intend to refer to it using jQuery post.  All scripts have been commented out in the template as well.

My code in views.py is:

```
if request.method == 'POST':
    limit = int(request.POST.get('numberPP'))
    arrange = request.POST.get('arrangeBy')
    pageNumber = request.POST.get('pageNumber')
else:   
    limit = 10
    arrange = 'id'
    pageNumber = 1
rawScores = score.objects.filter(userID=request.user).order_by('-'+arrange)
scoresPaginator = Paginator(rawScores,limit)
try:
    pScores = scoresPaginator.page(pageNumber)
except PageNotAnInteger:
    pScores = scoresPaginator.page(1)
except EmptyPage:
    pScores = scoresPaginator(scoresPaginator.num_pages)
return render(request,'scores/scoresview.html',{'scores':pScores,'arrange':arrange,'numberPP':limit})
```

What am I doing wrong? Thank you

EDIT
The first time the page is loaded it is a GET.  The data is setup in the else part of the the if statement.  The error is thrown on the first loading of the page.  Below is the full traceback of the error.

```
Internal Server Error: /scores/scoresview
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:\OneDrive\OU\OUYEAR~4\TM470\Django\project\pjaenv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 41, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "E:\OneDrive\OU\OUYEAR~4\TM470\Django\project\pjaenv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 187, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "E:\OneDrive\OU\OUYEAR~4\TM470\Django\project\pjaenv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 185, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "E:\OneDrive\OU\OU Year 4\TM470\Django\project\tm470\scores\views.py", line 67, in scoresview
    return render(request,'scores/scoresview.html',{'scores':pScores,'arrange':arrange,'numberPP':limit})
  File "E:\OneDrive\OU\OUYEAR~4\TM470\Django\project\pjaenv\lib\site-packages\django\shortcuts.py", line 30, in render
    content = loader.render_to_string(template_name, context, request, using=using)
  File "E:\OneDrive\OU\OUYEAR~4\TM470\Django\project\pjaenv\lib\site-packages\django\template\loader.py", line 68, in render_to_string
    return template.render(context, request)
  File "E:\OneDrive\OU\OUYEAR~4\TM470\Django\project\pjaenv\lib\site-packages\django\template\backends\django.py", line 66, in render
    return self.template.render(context)
  File "E:\OneDrive\OU\OUYEAR~4\TM470\Django\project\pjaenv\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 207, in render
    return self._render(context)
  File "E:\OneDrive\OU\OUYEAR~4\TM470\Django\project\pjaenv\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 199, in _render
    return self.nodelist.render(context)
  File "E:\OneDrive\OU\OUYEAR~4\TM470\Django\project\pjaenv\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 990, in render
    bit = node.render_annotated(context)
  File "E:\OneDrive\OU\OUYEAR~4\TM470\Django\project\pjaenv\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 957, in render_annotated
    return self.render(context)
  File "E:\OneDrive\OU\OUYEAR~4\TM470\Django\project\pjaenv\lib\site-packages\django\template\loader_tags.py", line 177, in render
    return compiled_parent._render(context)
  File "E:\OneDrive\OU\OUYEAR~4\TM470\Django\project\pjaenv\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 199, in _render
    return self.nodelist.render(context)
  File "E:\OneDrive\OU\OUYEAR~4\TM470\Django\project\pjaenv\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 990, in render
    bit = node.render_annotated(context)
  File "E:\OneDrive\OU\OUYEAR~4\TM470\Django\project\pjaenv\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 957, in render_annotated
    return self.render(context)
  File "E:\OneDrive\OU\OUYEAR~4\TM470\Django\project\pjaenv\lib\site-packages\django\template\loader_tags.py", line 72, in render
    result = block.nodelist.render(context)
  File "E:\OneDrive\OU\OUYEAR~4\TM470\Django\project\pjaenv\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 990, in render
    bit = node.render_annotated(context)
  File "E:\OneDrive\OU\OUYEAR~4\TM470\Django\project\pjaenv\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 957, in render_annotated
    return self.render(context)
  File "E:\OneDrive\OU\OUYEAR~4\TM470\Django\project\pjaenv\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 1040, in render
    output = self.filter_expression.resolve(context)
  File "E:\OneDrive\OU\OUYEAR~4\TM470\Django\project\pjaenv\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 708, in resolve
    obj = self.var.resolve(context)
  File "E:\OneDrive\OU\OUYEAR~4\TM470\Django\project\pjaenv\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 849, in resolve
    value = self._resolve_lookup(context)
  File "E:\OneDrive\OU\OUYEAR~4\TM470\Django\project\pjaenv\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 911, in _resolve_lookup
    current = current()
  File "E:\OneDrive\OU\OUYEAR~4\TM470\Django\project\pjaenv\lib\site-packages\django\core\paginator.py", line 155, in previous_page_number
    return self.paginator.validate_number(self.number - 1)
  File "E:\OneDrive\OU\OUYEAR~4\TM470\Django\project\pjaenv\lib\site-packages\django\core\paginator.py", line 45, in validate_number
    raise EmptyPage(_('That page number is less than 1'))
django.core.paginator.EmptyPage: That page number is less than 1
[10/Jul/2017 09:17:35] "GET /scores/scoresview HTTP/1.1" 500 172512
```

The error appears to arise from view.py on line 67.  This is the line:

```
return render(request,'scores/scoresview.html',{'scores':pScores,'arrange':arrange,'numberPP':limit})
```

I hope this extra information helps.

Comment: Can you print out what your `request.POST` contains? Also, please post the full traceback.

Comment: problem is here: pScores = scoresPaginator.page(pageNumber) . This exception is caught: except EmptyPage: . Check the value of pageNumber.

Comment: I have amended the post to include the traceback and some more information.  Thank you.

Comment: Another thought.  If the error was arising at the pScores = scoresPaginator.page(pageNumber) line then I would expect it to be caught by the except EmptyPage.  It is not.  The error is thrown when the return render is called.  Changing the value of pageNumber has no affect.  Removing 'scores':pScores from the render data makes the page load correctly but with no data.  Passing the rawScores ('scores':rawScores) shows all the data when the code in the template is un-commented.

Answer (score 0):

Finally made progress on this problem.  What I did not realise is that when Django passes a template page it does not take any notice of comment tags.  There is some kind of error in my java script on the template page.  I had commented all the script code out.  But Django was still trying to passe the script.  When the scripts where deleted the page loaded with the correct data on it.